# How to manage roles in ASP MVC with EF and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.
I am also using Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a 3 types of Users : Root, Super User and Admin .

Infact, in my base I have table User and table "Type_Account" which contain those 3 types of roles.

Each type of user have its rights of access.

To manage that, I found some tutorials on the Internet that i used : /asp.netwebadminfiles/security/roles/manageAllRoles.aspx

I wonder if I could manage those role with that even as I am using base ??

Answer (score 0):

ASP NET give you some options to manage authentication (user and password) and authorization(roles), if you want to use you own database structure you should create a custom Memebership and RoleProvider

[MSDN Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[MSDN Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tksy7hd7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)